# cv::Rect functionality in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

It seems the Python interface for OpenCV doesn't provide a corresponding class for `cv::Rect`. Is its functionality ported in the form of some functions in python?

I have tried the below code in C++ and same in python and got some errors:

`border2=5
 cv::Rect rectangle(border,border,image.cols-border2,image.rows-border2);`

But when I try python code as follows

`rect=cv2.rectangle(border,border,img.shape[1]-border2,img.shape[0]-border2);`

**Error**:`rect=cv2.rectangle(border,border,img.shape[1]-border2,img.shape[0]-border2);`

Comment: `cv2.rectangle`, similar to `cv::rectangle`, is the function to draw a rectangle on a `mat`.

Comment: Try `cv2.rectangle(border,border,img.shape[1]-border2,img.shape[0]-border2)` instead without assigning it to a variable.

Comment: I don't think cv::Rect or cv::Rect_ were implemented in Python because it is preferable to use slices instead. You can try `img[ border:img.shape[1]-border2, border:img.shape[0]-border2 ]`. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like:

```
cv2.rectangle(img, (border, border), (img.shape[1]-border2,img.shape[0]-border2), color, thickness = 1)
```